# Redimensioning iOS UIViews

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, autoresize

I have a screen with multiple subviews on iOS, when I have to adjust one view size I must resize all the other views with new frame values.
Is there any way to do this automatically ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout is your friend and will do what you want automatically (once you have set it up).

Have a read of the documentation on it here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html